# Angular using filter to Update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to update my model using `$filter` or some other smart way without having to do multiple `for each`.
So basically I have my model similar to below:

```
$scope.projects = [
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        name: 'task name',
        visible: true,
        starred: true
      }
    ],
    createdAt: 'something'
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        name: 'second task name',
        visible: true,
        starred: false
      }
    ],
    createdAt: 'something'
  }
]
```

What I wanted to do is by using `$filter` or some other way like `underscore` and so on, to update the content of the variable. So for instance, when I click a button, I'd like to set `visible = true` only to tasks that are starred.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve that? Is it possible or I would have to do a couple of loops?

Something like:

`$filter('filter')($scope.projects, {{starred = true}}).tasks.visible = true`

**UPDATE**

With the help from @jbrown I was able to achieve what I wanted. 
Just in case someone needs similar approach, the final solution was as written below:

```
_.forEach($scope.projectsModel.projects, function(proj){
    _.forEach(_.filter(proj.tasks, {starred: true}), function(task){
        task.visible = true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using underscore you can use a combination of filter and find to get the results you are looking for.

```
  $scope.filteredProjects = _.filter($scope.projects, function(proj) {
                                return _.find(proj.tasks, { 
                                    visible: true, starred: true });
                             });
```

Comment: Hi jbrown! your answer is 95% exactly what I need! :) What I need now is to set value based on this filter.. I need that on this filter, I set the visible to true, where starred is true.. is there some method in underscore that `sets` instead of the find ?

Comment: Ah! With your help I was able to do it.. I'm marking your answer as correct for enlightening on how to do that.. I'm gonna post my solution just in case someone needs it too..